# Why in algebraic data types, if I can define a special `from` and `to` function for two types, the two types can be considered equality?

Tags: haskell, equality, algebraic-data-types

I'm reading this blog: http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/

It says:

> However, when I talk about equality, I don’t mean Haskell equality, in the sense of the (==) function. Instead, I mean that the two types are in one-to-one correspondence – that is, when I say that two types a and b are equal, I mean that you could write two functions
>
> ```
>     from :: a -> b
>     to   :: b -> a
> ```
>
> that pair up values of a with values of b, so that the following equations always hold (here the == is genuine, Haskell-flavored equality):
>
> ```
>     to (from a) == a
>     from (to b) == b
> ```

And later, there are many laws based on this definition:

```
Add Void a === a
Add a b === Add b a
Mul Void a === Void
Mul () a === a
Mul a b === Mul b a
```

I can't understand why we can safely get these laws based on the definition of "equality"? Can use use other definitions? What can we do with this definition? Does it make sense for Haskell type systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term that the author is skating around, so as not to "mention category theory or advanced math", is *cardinality*. He defines two types to be `===`-equal to each other if they have equal cardinality -- that is, if there are as many possible values of one as there are of the other.

Because if two types have equal cardinality, there exists an *isomorphism* between them. `Mul () Bool` may be a different type than `Bool`, but there are exactly as many members of one as the other, and one can trivially define a function to go from one to the other, or the other to the one. (Not that there is only one such isomorphism -- the point is, you could choose one.)

It's not a great approach. It works fine for finite sets, basically, but it introduces unfortunate side effects for infinite sets, like `Add Int Int === Int`. Still, for the basic description of addition and multiplication of types, it seems to serve.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. In order to understand this well, e.g. `cardinality`, `category theory`, could you recommend me any book?

Comment: Also, ``Add Int Int`` and ``Int`` do not have the same equality because ``Int`` is a 32-bit integer. For the type arbitrary big numbers you would write ``Integer``.

Comment: @Freewind "Conceptual Mathematics: A first introduction to categories" is a good, easy to read introduction to category theory that doesn't require much in the way of prerequisite math knowledge. Because of this, however, it doesn't get *too* deep into the subject but it is a good start. It does cover the idea of isomorphism though (and some related ideas). Also, you wouldn't happen to be the same Sneftel from GDNet would you? Small world

Comment: @Freewind Also, you might want to look up the idea of an equivalence relation and try to prove that this definition of equality satisfies that the equivalence relation laws as an exercise.

Comment: @Freewind Oh, also, there's a book "Homotopy Type Theory" that goes into a lot of detail about what it means for two types to be equal to each other (values too) and the implications of that (and how that idea actually has a strong connection to the idea of a homotopy from topology and homotopy theory). It's more in depth, but *significantly* more difficult than Conceptual Mathematics (I'm still working through Homotopy Type Theory and I'm struggling some), but eventually you might be interested in looking at it. I'd definitely suggest starting with Conceptual Mathematics though.

Comment: @DavidYoung, thank you very much! I will find these books, hope I can learn more about types

Comment: @DavidYoung Yep, that's me.

Answer (score 2):

Informally speaking, when two mathematical structures `A,B` have two "nice" functions `from,to` satifying `from . to == id` and `to . from == id`, the structures `A,B` are said to be **isomorphic**.

The actual definition of "nice" function varies with the kind of structure at hand (and sometimes, different definitions of "nice" give rise to distinct notions of isomorphism).

The idea behind isomorphic structures is that, roughly, they "work" in exactly the same way. For instance, consider a structure A made by the booleans `True,False` with `&&,||` as operations. Let then structure B made of  the two naturals`1,0`  with `min,max` as operations. These are different structures, yet they share the same rules. For instance `True && x == x` and `` 1 `min` x == x `` for all `x`. A and B are isomorphic: function `to` will map `True` to `1`, and `False` to `0`, while `from` will perform the opposite mapping.

(Note that while we could map `True` to `0` and `False` to `1`, and we would still get `from . to == id` and its dual, this mapping would not be considered "nice" since it would not preserve the structure: e.g., `to (True && x) == to x` yet `` to (True && x) == to True `min` to x == 0 `min` to x == 0 `` .)

Another example in a different setting: consider A to be a circle in a plane, while B is a square in such plane. One can then define *continuous* mappings `to,from` between them. This can be done with any two "closed loops", loosely speaking, which can be said to be isomorphic. Instead a circle and an "eight" shape do not admit such continuous mappings: the self-intersecting point in the "eight" can not be mapped to any point in the circle in a continuous way (roughly, four "ways" depart from it, while points in the circle have only two such "ways").

In Haskell, types are similarly said to be isomorphic when two Haskell-definable functions `from,to` exist between them satisfying the rules above. Here being a "nice" function just means being definable in Haskell. The linked [web blog](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/) shows a few such isomorphic types. Here's another example, using recursive types:

```
List1 a = Add Unit (Mul a (List1 a))
List2 a = Add Unit (Add a (Mul a (Mul a (List2 a))))
```

Intuitively, the first reads as: "a list is either the empty list, or a pair made of an element and a list". The second reads as: "a list is either the empty list, or a single element, or a triple make of an element, another element, and a list". One can convert between the two by handling the elements two at a time.

Another example:

```
Tree a = Add Unit (Mul a (Mul (Tree a) (Tree a)))
```

You can prove that the type `Tree Unit` is isomorphic to `List1 (Tree Unit)` by exploiting the algebraic laws fond in the blog. Below, `=` stands for isomorphism.

```
List1 (Tree Unit)
-- definition of List1 a
= Add Unit (Mul (Tree Unit) (List1 (Tree Unit))) 
-- by inductive hypothesis, the inner `List1 (Tree Unit)` is isomorphic to `Tree Unit`
= Add Unit (Mul (Tree Unit) (Tree Unit))
-- definition of Tree a
= Tree Unit
```

The above proof sketch induces the function `to` as follows.

```
data Add a b = InL a | InR b
data Mul a b = P a b
type Unit = ()
newtype List1 a = List1 (Add Unit (Mul a (List1 a)))
newtype Tree a  = Tree  (Add Unit (Mul a (Mul (Tree a) (Tree a))))

to :: List1 (Tree Unit) -> Tree Unit
to (List1 (InL ())) = Tree (InL ())
to (List1 (InR (P t ts))) = Tree (InR (P () (P t (to ts))))
```

Note how recursive call plays the role the inductive hypothesis has in the proof.

Writing `from` is left as an exercise :-P

Comment: One can make a good case for that it's wise to label notions of isomorphism differently depending on what you call _nice_ – and indeed that's done throughout much of mathematics, for instance in the continuous case it's very seldom called "isomorphic" but _homeomorphic_; if you add analyticity it's _diffeomorphic_ etc..

Answer (score 0):

> Why in algebraic data types, if I can define a special `from` and `to` function for two types, the two types can be considered equal?

Well, the better term to use here isn't "equal," but rather **isomorphic**.  The thing is that when two types are isomorphic, they are basically interchangeable with each other; any program  written in terms of `A` could, in principle, be written in terms of `B` instead, without changing the meaning of the program.  Suppose you have:

```
from :: A -> B
to   :: B -> A
```

and these two functions constitute an isomorphism, that is:

```
to (from a) == a
from (to b) == b
```

Now, if you have any function that takes `A` as an argument, you can for example write a counterpart that takes `B` as an argument instead:

```
foo :: B -> Something
foo = originalFoo . from
    where originalFoo :: A -> Something
          originalFoo a = ...
```

And for any function that produces an `A`, you can likewise do this:

```
bar :: Something -> B
bar = to . originalBar
    where originalBar :: Something -> A
          originalBar something = ...
```

Now you've hidden all uses of `A` inside the `where` subdefinitions.  You could continue down this path and mechanically eliminate all uses of `A` entirely, and you're guaranteed the program will work the same as when you started.